# jquery input not checked image path change

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I don't know how it works, so I hope you can help me. 
I wanna change the image path of my pictures, if the input field is unchecked. 
If it checked, it changed the path to a colored picture, that works fine for me, but if I choose another image, the image before should change back to a black and white one.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the html:

```js
$('input[name=an_paymentOptionsControl]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).siblings('img').attr('src', 'pics/payment-large/' + this.getAttribute('value') + '.png');
  console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
});

$('input[name=an_paymentOptionsControl]').not(':checked', function() {
  $('img').attr('src', 'pics/payment-large/sw' + this.getAttribute('value') + '.png');
  console.log('nix');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anm-payment-layout-methods">
  <label>
          <input class="anm-pay-method" type="radio" value="acc" name="an_paymentOptionsControl" />
          <img class="paymentLabel" src="pics/payment-large/swacc.png">
        </label>
  <label>
          <input class="anm-pay-method" type="radio" value="paypal" name="an_paymentOptionsControl" />
          <img src="pics/payment-large/swpaypal.png">
        </label>
  <label>
            <input class="anm-pay-method" type="radio" value="sue" name="an_paymentOptionsControl" />
            <img src="pics/payment-large/swsue.png">
        </label>
  <label>
            <input class="anm-pay-method" type="radio" value="giropay" name="an_paymentOptionsControl" />
            <img src="pics/payment-large/swgiropay.png">
        </label>
  <label>
            <input class="anm-pay-method" type="radio" value="prepay" name="an_paymentOptionsControl" />
            <img src="pics/payment-large/swprepay.png">
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: image before means previous image?

Comment: Post a working snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the path of images in the `change` event handler.

```
$('input[name=an_paymentOptionsControl]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).siblings('img').attr('src', 'pics/payment-large/' + this.value + '.png');

    //Reset images
    $('input[name=an_paymentOptionsControl]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
        $(this).siblings('img').attr('src', 'pics/payment-large/sw' + this.value + '.png');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Muuta, Glad I could help